# Firing and Capturing of Custom RoutedCommands within CustomControls for MenuItems

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, routed-commands

WPF. .NET 4.6

I'm trying to learn RoutedCommands. In the below code, my desire is to have my custom class of MenuItem respond to the user click by firing a custom routedcommand *which is **listened** to by the **parent** menuitem.* When the parent menuitem receives the routedcommand from its contained children, it is to set a dependency property allowing other elements in the visual tree to bind using ElementName binding. So far, I have been unable to capture the command at the parent container--so I am not sure if it is actually bubbling at all.

1. How can the command, ChangeInkAttributes, be routed up through the element tree to the top "InkMenu" element?
2. How does a child element, e.g. "InkAndGestures", fire the routedcommand, ChangeInkAttributes, **from within** the customcontrol, InkMenuItem?
3. **How can the parent containter, "InkMenu", capture the routedcommand, "InkAndGestures"?** (Preferrably capture the routedcommand within the custom control -- is this even possible?)

Note: I would like to avoid any/all code in code-behind.

I appreciate any help with this as a thorough search with Google has failed to show a good example of this approach.

TIA

As as example:

```
<pn:InkMenuItem x:Name="InkMenu" Header="Ink"  > <---**Parent containter to set
the dependency property and provide for ElementName binding.

THESE ARE THE CHILDREN WHICH SHOULD SEND THE COMMAND TO THE PARENT "InkMenu"

                    <pn:InkMenuItem Header="Pen"    />
                    <pn:InkMenuItem Header="HighLighter"  />
                    <Separator />
                    <pn:InkMenuItem Header="RePen Selection"  />
                    <pn:InkMenuItem Header="Select Strokes"  />
                    <pn:InkMenuItem Header="Select All Strokes"  />
                    <Separator />
                    <pn:InkMenuItem Header="Erase By Stroke" />
                    <pn:InkMenuItem Header="Erase By Point"  />
                    <pn:InkMenuItem Header="Clear Strokes"   />
                    <Separator />
                    <pn:InkMenuItem Header="Show Recognition Layout" />
                    <pn:InkMenuItem x:Name="InkAndGestures"  Header="Ink And Getsures" IsCheckable="True"/>
                </pn:InkMenuItem>
```

I've defined the InkMenuItem customcontrol simply as:

```
Generic.XAML:

 <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:InkMenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}"/>

InkMenuItem.cs:
    public class InkMenuItem : MenuItem
    {
        public static RoutedUICommand ChangeInkAttributes { get; }

        static InkMenuItem()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(InkMenuItem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(InkMenuItem)));

            //Instanciate the command
            ChangeInkAttributes = new RoutedUICommand("Change Ink Attributes", "ChangeInkAttributes", typeof(InkMenuItem));

            //Create the command binding
            CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(InkMenuItem), 
                new CommandBinding(
                    /*Command Object */  ChangeInkAttributes, 
                    /*Execute*/          ChangeInkAttributes_Executed, 
                    /*Can Execute? */    ChangeInkAttributes_CanExecute));

        }

        public static void ChangeInkAttributes_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            InkMenuItem inkmenuitem = sender as InkMenuItem;

            CommandParameter parameter = e.Parameter as CommandParameter;

            if (parameter != null)
                parameter.CanEditBeExecuted = true;

            if (inkmenuitem != null)
                inkmenuitem.changeInkAttributes();
        }


        public static void ChangeInkAttributes_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;  // can this command be executed?
            e.Handled = false;    // has this event been handled?
        }


        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
        }

        // Raise the MyChecked event when the InkMenuItem is clicked
        protected override void OnClick()
        {
           // base.OnClick();
            ChangeInkAttributes.Execute(null,this);
        }

        private void changeInkAttributes()
        {
            var h = Header.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(h+"23");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `RoutedCommand` searches the visual tree from the focused element and up for an element that has a matching `CommandBinding`, executes the `Execute` delegate for this particular `CommandBinding` and then stops.

It doesn't route or bubble up any further as Nick Kramer of Microsoft has stated here: https://www.vistax64.com/avalon/852-routedcommand-doesnt-route-ui-tree.html.

Comment: You are 100% correct (I wish I had known this before wasting two days). Please critique my simple change to make this bubble. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After pulling what little hair I have left out, I can safely vouch that @mm8  is 100% correct. However, I do want this to bubble anyway. So, I changed the

ChangeInkAttributes_Executed event to rethrow itself on its parent InkMenuItem:

```
public static void ChangeInkAttributes_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            InkMenuItem inkmenuitem = sender as InkMenuItem;

            CommandParameter parameter = e.Parameter as CommandParameter;

            if (parameter != null)
                parameter.CanEditBeExecuted = true;

            if (inkmenuitem != null)
                inkmenuitem.changeInkAttributes();

            // this only causes a loop, it does not bubble.
            // inkmenuitem.RaiseEvent(e);


            InkMenuItem parent = inkmenuitem.Parent as InkMenuItem;
            if (parent != null)
                parent.RaiseEvent(e);
        }
```

Hope this helps somebody.